# How to move an image in a plugin to the upload directory and make it as a media of wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development, images, uploads, media

How to move an image in a plugin to the upload directory and make it as a media of wordpress?

I would like to use them in posts.

**Expand question:**

I would like to generate images using other programs and saved in the temporary folder of my plugin directory.

*eg.* plugin-name/tmp/image_01.jpg

Then, I would like to upload the image to the upload directory an use it as a media source.

Is that possible?

Comment: Can you expand on why you need to do this?

Comment: @mrwweb Sure, is that clear? I hope that's helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`wp_insert_attachment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment). Takes an $attachment array of metadata and a $filename and inserts it into the media library. The Codex page has a good snippet so I won't include one here.

Comment: @goodseller if this answered your problem, make sure to accept it as the answer. Otherwise, update your question and explain why this didn't work.